# How can I paste stuff from my mac's clipboard to the iPhone simulator?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator, clipboard

I'm having a really hard time taking screenshots.

My app has a view controller that lets the user enter some information with a few `UITextField`s. I am now taking screenshots of this view controller so that I can upload them to iTunes Connect.

Obviously, I can't just leave the text fields blank and take a screenshot, because that tells the user little information about how he/she is supposed to do.

Therefore, I need to enter some dummy texts. But they cannot be

```
njndsfiusbfiksbksug
```

because it makes no sense and does not show the user what that text field is for.

So I have to enter some really long texts in there in order to show the user a good example of how to use the app.

Now here comes the problem, I have to take screenshots of 5 device sizes and 3 localizations. This means that I will spend a lot of time entering the same old text into the iPhone over and over.

Then I thought that I can type the dummy texts into the Stickies app on my Mac, and copy/paste that text from my Mac to the iPhone simulator. So I pressed <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in the Stickies app, and <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> in the iPhone, but nothing happens at all.

I think this is because the iPhone has its own clipboard.

How can I copy text from my Mac to the iPhone simulator?

Note: when the user is using the app, he/she can choose not to enter long texts. I'm just doing this to show a good example to the user. So don't tell me my app sucks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> when inside the simulator, then click on a field and tap `Paste`.

Comment: You mean I have to do two steps?

Comment: Yes. Pasting from your mac keyboard while in simulator copies what is on your mac's clipboard to the simulated iPhone's clipboard. From there, you must tap on the field you would like to paste into, then wait for the `Paste` button to appear then tap it.

Comment: Okay. Thanks! I got it!.